# Why does extracting an IO (Maybe Bool) using fromMaybe do both IO actions

Tags: haskell, io, lazy-evaluation

In this code:

```
 fromMaybe <$> (print "A" >> return True) <*> (print "B" >> (return $ Just False))
 fromMaybe <$> (print "A" >> return True) <*> (print "B" >> (return $ Nothing))
```

I expected that due to laziness, either "A" or "B" would be printed depending on whether I supply `Just something` or `Nothing` but instead both are printed no matter what. Can someone explain a) what is going on exactly here? and b) how can I achieve the effect I want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409260/what-advantage-does-monad-give-us-over-an-applicative/17412969

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Focusing on `(print "B" >> (return $ Just False))` you're sequencing a `print` command with a `return` in the `IO` `Monad`. Since it's a `Monad`, it needs to evaluate `print "B"` exactly enough to get the "value" (even though it's just ignored) before being able to evaluate the `return` statement. For `print` in the `IO` monad that means performing the side effect.

This sequencing occurs in both of the IO arguments and so before they're able to be passed to the pure computation, `fromMaybe`, all of the effects have already been executed. `Applicative`s always execute all of the effects *first* and then compute the pure computation on the pure values.

```
fromMaybe True <$> case thing of
  Just _  -> print "A" >> return thing
  Nothing -> print "B" >> return thing
```

or maybe `fromMaybe True <$> when (isJust thing) (print "A") >> print "B" >> return thing` if that's better behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The following happens:

You map fromMaybe over an IO value. Hence the left part

```
fromMaybe <$> (print "A" >> return True)
```

is an IO action that could be rewritten thus

```
print "A" >> return (fromMaybe True) :: IO (Maybe Bool -> Bool)
```

This means that the "A" will be printed no matter what.

Note that the IO monad is all about sequencing actions, hence an action later in the >>= chain can **never** affect whether earlier actions are executed.

Consider

```
fromMaybe <$> (getChar >>= return)
```

It is clear that the Char the fromMaybe is applied to must come from actually reading a character. It is not the case that the character will only be read when it is needed.

If this were so, the following code would not make sense:

```
do
    a <- getChar
    b <- getChar
    -- at this point, a and b have been actually read from stdin already
    return (a < b)
```

For, it is not known whether (<) evaluates its left or right argument first.

Rather, in any case, a gets the value of the first character read and b that of the second. And the meaning of the code snippet is, accordingly, to read two characters and to check whether the first character read is lower than the second.

Indeed, if an IO action would be executed only when its value is actually needed, many programs wouldn't print anything, as it stands. This is because code like

```
 print "A" >> print "B"
```

deliberately ignores the result of the first print.

For the same reason, the "B" will always be printed.