# Difference between Monad and Applicative in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

I just read the following from [typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Intuition_3) about the difference between `Monad` and `Applicative`. I can understand that there is no `join` in `Applicative`. But the following description looks vague to me and I couldn't figure out what exactly is meant by "the result" of a monadic computation/action. So, if I put a value into `Maybe`, which makes a monad, what is the result of this "computation"?

> Let’s look more closely at the type of (>>=). The basic intuition is
>   that it combines two computations into one larger computation. The
>   first argument, m a, is the first computation. However, it would be
>   boring if the second argument were just an m b; then there would be no
>   way for the computations to interact with one another (actually, this
>   is exactly the situation with Applicative). So, the second argument to
>   (>>=) has type a -> m b: a function of this type, given a result of
>   the first computation, can produce a second computation to be run.
>   ... Intuitively, it is this ability to use the output from previous
>   computations to decide what computations to run next that makes Monad
>   more powerful than Applicative. The structure of an Applicative
>   computation is fixed, whereas the structure of a Monad computation can
>   change based on intermediate results.

Is there a concrete example illustrating "ability to use the output from previous computations to decide what computations to run next", which Applicative does not have?

Comment: `Just 1` describes a "computation", whose "result" is 1. `Nothing` describes a computation which produces no results.

Comment: See also [arrowdodger](http://stackoverflow.com/users/637669/arrowdodger)'s question ["What advantage does Monad give us over an Applicative?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17409260/237428), which has some good answers (full disclosure: including one of mine).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

My favorite example is the "purely applicative Either". We'll start by analyzing the base Monad instance for Either

```
instance Monad (Either e) where
  return = Right
  Left e  >>= _ = Left e
  Right a >>= f = f a
```

This instance embeds a very natural short-circuiting notion: we proceed from left to right and once a single computation "fails" into the `Left` then all the rest do as well. There's also the natural `Applicative` instance that any `Monad` has

```
instance Applicative (Either e) where
  pure  = return
  (<*>) = ap
```

where `ap` is nothing more than left-to-right sequencing before a `return`:

```
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap mf ma = do 
  f <- mf
  a <- ma
  return (f a)
```

---

Now the trouble with this `Either` instance comes to light when you'd like to collect error messages which occur anywhere in a computation and somehow produce a summary of errors. This flies in the face of short-circuiting. It also flies in the face of the type of `(>>=)`

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

If we think of `m a` as "the past" and `m b` as "the future" then `(>>=)` produces the future from the past so long as it can run the "stepper" `(a -> m b)`. This "stepper" demands that the value of `a` really exists in the future... and this is impossible for `Either`. Therefore `(>>=)` *demands* short-circuiting.

So instead we'll implement an `Applicative` instance which cannot have a corresponding `Monad`.

```
instance Monoid e => Applicative (Either e) where
  pure = Right
```

Now the implementation of `(<*>)` is the special part worth considering carefully. It performs some amount of "short-circuiting" in its first *3* cases, but does something interesting in the fourth.

```
  Right f <*> Right a = Right (f a)     -- neutral
  Left  e <*> Right _ = Left e          -- short-circuit
  Right _ <*> Left  e = Left e          -- short-circuit
  Left e1 <*> Left e2 = Left (e1 <> e2) -- combine!
```

Notice again that if we think of the left argument as "the past" and the right argument as "the future" then `(<*>)` is special compared to `(>>=)` as it's allowed to "open up" the future and the past in parallel instead of necessarily needing results from "the past" in order to compute "the future".

This means, directly, that we can use our purely `Applicative` `Either` to collect errors, ignoring `Right`s if any `Left`s exist in the chain

```
> Right (+1) <*> Left [1] <*> Left [2]
> Left [1,2]
```

---

So let's flip this intuition on its head. What can we not do with a purely applicative `Either`? Well, since its operation depends upon examining the future prior to running the past, we must be able to determine the structure of the future without depending upon values in the past. In other words, we cannot write

```
ifA :: Applicative f => f Bool -> f a -> f a -> f a
```

which satisfies the following equations

```
ifA (pure True)  t e == t
ifA (pure False) t e == e
```

while we can write `ifM`

```
ifM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a
ifM mbool th el = do
  bool <- mbool
  if bool then th else el
```

such that

```
ifM (return True)  t e == t
ifM (return False) t e == e
```

This impossibility arises because `ifA` embodies exactly the idea of the result computation depending upon the values embedded in the argument computations.

Comment: what's wrong with `ifA t c a = g <$> t <*> c <*> a where g b x y = if b then x else y`?

Comment: @WillNess: That always uses all the computational structure/runs all the effects.  For instance, `ifA (Just True) (Just ()) Nothing == Nothing`, whereas `ifM (Just True) (Just ()) Nothing == Just ()`.  It'd probably be more accurate to say "we cannot write `ifA` *with the expected semantics*".

Comment: @AntalS-Z ah, yes, thank you. Then again, in the Applicative, this *would* be the expected semantics, wouldn't it? The issue is, whether we can influence the *shape* of a computation *past* the point we're at. Maybe `ifX` is not a good vehicle to explore this issue.

Comment: This is a good point, thanks @WillNess and AntalS-Z. These comments are exactly on point—given that this is mostly an ancillary issue, though, I'll just edit the answer to suggest reading these comments for more detail.

Comment: I'd argue that `ifM` is exactly the vehicle for examining the power of monad, though it does assume that `ifM` is the expected semantics not `if' <$> a <*> b <*> c where if' b t e = if b then t else e`. The real challenge is when effects get conflated with values.

Comment: yes, `ifM` is indeed the essence of Monad's distinction. But for Applicative, `ifA` is nothing special, the `if` happens on the inside still... the signatures just are superficially similar (IOW it's confusing :)).

Comment: I'll add the specs required to describe `ifA` beyond just its type.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. The 'ifA' example greatly helped me understand the issue. I have interpreted your example from another perspective also in typeclassopedia (i.e. absence of 'join') in an answer, just for reference.

Comment: I think it's critical to note that when a type has a `Monad` instance defined,  its `Applicative` instance **must** be compatible with that `Monad` instance (`pure = return`, (<*>) = ap`). While the second `Applicative` instance definition in this answer satisfies the `Applicative` laws, it violates this documented requirement. The proper way to get this second `Applicative` instance is to define it for some other type that's isomorphic to `Either`.

Comment: Note also that the `Errors` type in [`Control.Applicative.Lift`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Lift.html) implements precisely the "collect all errors" behavior described in this answer.

Comment: @LuisCasillas That's good to note—my `Either` code here assumes that we've dropped the `base` `Monad` instance. I also did not know about `Lift (Constant e)`. That's wonderful!

Answer (score 53):

`Just 1` describes a "computation", whose "result" is 1. `Nothing` describes a computation which produces no results.

The difference between a Monad and an Applicative is that in the Monad there's a choice. The key distinction of Monads is the ability to choose between different paths in computation (not just break out early). Depending on a value produced by a previous step in computation, the rest of computation structure can change.

Here's what this means. In the monadic chain

```
return 42            >>= (\x ->
if x == 1
   then
        return (x+1) 
   else 
        return (x-1) >>= (\y -> 
        return (1/y)     ))
```

the `if` chooses what computation to construct.

In case of Applicative, in

```
pure (1/) <*> ( pure (+(-1)) <*> pure 1 )
```

all the functions work "inside" computations, there's no chance to break up a chain. Each function just transforms a value it's fed. The "shape" of the computation structure is entirely "on the outside" from the functions' point of view.

A function could return a special value to indicate failure, but it can't cause next steps in the computation to be skipped. They all will have to process the special value in a special way too. The shape of the computation can not be changed according to received value.

With monads, the functions themselves construct computations to their choosing.

Comment: This example demonstrates a few things _succintly_ : You can not only transform values as with applicative functors, but you can also ... 1) store the history of computations anywhere within a chain of monadic operations, 2) decide how, and when to transform values (if the values are to be transformed at all) (in a possibly non-linear manner) based on the history of computations saved, 3) model side-effects within the body of these monadic operations, 4) more trivially, use `do-block` notation.

Comment: cf. this, later, related, [answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34561605/849891) for some clarifying comparisons.

Comment: The one marked as correct is useless, while this unswer really helps especially when you are not familiar with the language...

Comment: @Ivan it might be harder for non-Haskellers, but it is much better actually. The key difference is that all computation descriptions involved in the applicative's combination (`a <*> b <*> ...` ) are known upfront; but with Monadic combination ( `a >>= (\ ... -> b >>= ... )` ) each next computation is calculated ("is dependent") on the value produced by the previous computation. there are two timelines involved, two worlds: a pure one where computation descriptions (`a`, `b` ...) are created and combined, and a potentially impure one where they are "run" - where actual computations happen.

Comment: a nice example of the difference is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467803/how-to-handle-side-effect-with-applicative/24467994#24467994).

Comment: Thanks for the illustration in the link. Your answers have been really helpful compared to many other answers. Would you say the following understanding makes sense? Or maybe I still got something wrong/inaccurate.

Comment: - Functor: Just do stuffs within the container without caring about the shape of the container at all.
- Applicative: Also able to take into account the shape of the container. e.g. if there's a "Nothing" shape in the pipeline, output Nothing.
- Monad: In addition, also be able to accumulate intermediate results during the pipeline and potentially change the computations to be performed later in the pipeline.

Comment: Functor: yes. moreover, you're not able to even see the structure/shape. Monad: yes, not "accumulate" though, but the main thing is create the next computation based on the result produced by the previous computation in the chain. Applicative: lack that ability; computations are combined without regard to values they produce, and in fact, prior to them even running, so way before there even are any results in existence. about Nothing though, it is part of the shape, so even fmap deals with it, no need to have Applicative for it. Best analogy I came up with for myself is this: ...

Comment: with Functors we get to write: `for x in xs: emit (foo x)`. Applicatives enable us to write `for x in xs and y in ys: emit (bar x y)`. and Monads, `for x in xs: for y in (baz x): emit (bar x y)`. or with monad comprehensions, F: `[f x | x <- xs]`, A: `[bar x y | (x , y) <- (xs , ys)]` (kind of), M: `[bar x y | x <- xs, y <- baz x]`. Functors are *generalized modifiable "loops"* (with `fmap`). Applicatives are generalized *combinable* "loops" (aka "monoidal functors", with `combine :: (f a, f b) -> f (a,b)`). Monads are generalized *nested* "loops" (with `join :: f (f a) -> f a`). @xji

Comment: F: `fmap foo xs = [foo x | x <- xs]`. A: `liftA2 bar xs ys = fmap (uncurry bar) (combine xs ys) = [bar x y | (x , y) <- combine xs ys ]`. M: `(xs >>= baz) = join (fmap baz xs) = join [baz x | x <- xs] = [y | x <- xs, y <- baz x]`.

Comment: Right. I see now. For the `Nothing` example, the `fmap` definition itself takes care of it since `fmap f Nothing = Nothing`. `Nothing` is a data constructor for `Maybe`, so technically speaking, `Nothing` satisfies type `f a` but also satisfies type `f b`. Therefore `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` always holds if the second argument and the result are `Nothing`.

Comment: It's not that the function `f` sees the `Nothing` shape, but that `fmap` already took care of it in a sense. `f` doesn't practically get to do anything if the input is `Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples. They're very helpful. Basically `Applicative` can combine two container and thus the shape/structure information can be used in some way during the combination I guess. Then `Monad` goes further in that you can create a different next computation during the process based on the previous computation.

Comment: The function of type `(a -> b)` I meant*, not necessarily called `f` I guess.

Comment: "Applicative can combine ... Monad goes further ..." exactly! also, `Nothing` is a "polymorphic constant". It can denote a value of type `Maybe Char`, `Maybe Int`, etc, depending on context. so it is really many things, which just look the same when written down. at each specific use it is just one thing, as expected. Imagine writing `fmap f m = case m of Just x -> Just (f x) ; n@Nothing -> n`. I think it won't compile. :) ..... wrong, it does, but the type is `(a -> a) -> Maybe a -> Maybe a`! because the _same_ thing, `n`, is used for the result. without `n`, it's a *new* `Nothing`. cheers :)

Comment: @WillNess Would you find the following to be a good explanation? It's similar to what @xji was saying: 

"both monads and applicatives both allow the creation of pipelines which combine one or more contexts. The main difference is that monads allow the pipeline to access to the result of the previous computations, which can be useful for control flow. For monads, access to the previous value in the pipeline is allowed because `(a -> m b)` accepts an argument, whereas for applicatives `f (a -> b)` is “hidden” behind a context, so it can’t take an argument."

Comment: @cgoates no, _applicatives_ do not create new pipelines. the two pipelines are already there. _monad_ is able to create the second pipeline depending on the _results_ delivered by the first. for monads, `(a -> m b)` _creates_ the new pipeline `m b` based on the results `a` from previous computation step, `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. applicatives combine two pipelines which are already there: it is either `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` which accesses the results in first, and in second, then combines those results by applying (calling) the first with the second; ...

Comment: ... or it is `combineA :: f a -> f b -> f (a,b)` (or we might call it `zipA`) which lets us define the `(<*>)` with the help of `fmap` (which we already have, since Applicative builds on the Functor): `fab <*> fa = fmap (\(ab,a) -> ab a) (combineA fab fa)`. both ways to define Applicatives are interchangeable; Haskell went with the first. the second is a bit more clear I think, the first muddies it a little bit by lumping together the combining of "shapes/contexts" and the application of the "results inside them". see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561605/849891) for an illustration.

Answer (score 19):

The key of the difference can be observed in the type of `ap` vs type of `=<<`.

```
ap :: m (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)
=<< :: (a -> m b) -> (m a -> m b)
```

In both cases there is `m a`, but only in the second case `m a` can decide whether the function `(a -> m b)` gets applied. In its turn, the function `(a -> m b)` can "decide" whether the function bound next gets applied - by producing such `m b` that does not "contain" `b` (like `[]`, `Nothing` or `Left`).

In `Applicative` there is no way for functions "inside" `m (a -> b)` to make such "decisions" - they always produce a value of type `b`.

```
f 1 = Nothing -- here f "decides" to produce Nothing
f x = Just x

Just 1 >>= f >>= g -- g doesn't get applied, because f decided so.
```

In `Applicative` this is not possible, so can't show a example. The closest is:

```
f 1 = 0
f x = x

g <$> f <$> Just 1 -- oh well, this will produce Just 0, but can't stop g
                   -- from getting applied
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is my take on @J. Abrahamson's example as to why `ifA` cannot use the value inside e.g. `(pure True)`. In essence, it still boils down to the absence of the `join` function from `Monad` in `Applicative`, which unifies the two different perspectives given in [typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Intuition_3) to explain the difference between `Monad` and `Applicative`.

So using @J. Abrahamson's example of purely applicative `Either`:

```
instance Monoid e => Applicative (Either e) where
  pure = Right

  Right f <*> Right a = Right (f a)     -- neutral
  Left  e <*> Right _ = Left e          -- short-circuit
  Right _ <*> Left  e = Left e          -- short-circuit
  Left e1 <*> Left e2 = Left (e1 <> e2) -- combine!
```

(which has similar short-circuiting effect to the `Either` `Monad`), and the `ifA` function

```
ifA :: Applicative f => f Bool -> f a -> f a -> f a
```

What if we try to achieve the mentioned equations:

```
ifA (pure True)  t e == t
ifA (pure False) t e == e
```

?

Well, as already pointed out, ultimately, the content of `(pure True)`, cannot be used by a later computation. But technically speaking, this isn't right. We **can** use the content of `(pure True)` since a `Monad` is also a `Functor` with `fmap`. We can do:

```
ifA' b t e = fmap (\x -> if x then t else e) b
```

The problem is with the return type of `ifA'`, which is `f (f a)`. In `Applicative`, there is no way of collapsing two nested `Applicative`S into one. But this collapsing function is precisely what `join` in `Monad` performs. So,

```
ifA = join . ifA'
```

will satisfy the equations for `ifA`, if we can implement `join` appropriately. What `Applicative` is missing here is exactly the `join` function. In other words, we can somehow use the result from the previous result in `Applicative`. But doing so in an `Applicative` framework will involve augmenting the type of the return value to a nested applicative value, which we have no means to bring back to a single-level applicative value. This will be a serious problem because, e.g., we cannot compose functions using `Applicative`S appropriately. Using `join` fixes the issue, but the very introduction of `join` promotes the `Applicative` to a `Monad`.

Comment: Is the problem joining here that these 3 are okay: `join Right (Right a) = Right a; join Right (Left e) = Left e; join Left (Left e) = Left e` but this is no good: `join Left (Right a) =? Left (Right a)`?

Comment: Actually trying it out a bit for the first time, I see I'm ending up in a mess of a type for `join`'s argument of `Result<Result<_,_>,Result<_,_>>`, or worse.

Answer (score 6):

> But the following description looks vague to me and I couldn't figure out what exactly is meant by "the result" of a monadic computation/action.

Well, that vagueness is somewhat deliberate, because what "the result" is of a monadic computation is something that depends on each type.  The best answer is a bit tautological: the "result" (or *results*, since there can be more than one) is whatever value(s) the instance's implementation of `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` invokes the function argument with.

> So, if I put a value into `Maybe`, which makes a monad, what is the result of this "computation"?

The `Maybe` monad looks like this:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    return = Just
    Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
    Just a >>= k = k a
```

The only thing in here that qualifies as a "result" is the `a` in the second equation for `>>=`, because it's the only thing that ever gets "fed" to the second argument of `>>=`.

Other answers have gone into depth about the `ifA` vs. `ifM` difference, so I thought I'd highlight another significant difference: **applicatives compose, monads don't**.  With `Monad`s, if you want to make a `Monad` that combines the effects of two existing ones, you have to rewrite one of them as a monad transformer.  In contrast, if you have two `Applicatives` you can easily make a more complex one out of them, as shown below. (Code is copypasted from [`transformers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0).)

```
-- | The composition of two functors.
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }

-- | The composition of two functors is also a functor.
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) x)

-- | The composition of two applicatives is also an applicative.
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
    pure x = Compose (pure (pure x))
    Compose f <*> Compose x = Compose ((<*>) <$> f <*> x)


-- | The product of two functors.
data Product f g a = Pair (f a) (g a)

-- | The product of two functors is also a functor.
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Product f g) where
    fmap f (Pair x y) = Pair (fmap f x) (fmap f y)

-- | The product of two applicatives is also an applicative.
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Product f g) where
    pure x = Pair (pure x) (pure x)
    Pair f g <*> Pair x y = Pair (f <*> x) (g <*> y)


-- | The sum of a functor @f@ with the 'Identity' functor
data Lift f a = Pure a | Other (f a)

-- | The sum of two functors is always a functor.
instance (Functor f) => Functor (Lift f) where
    fmap f (Pure x) = Pure (f x)
    fmap f (Other y) = Other (fmap f y)

-- | The sum of any applicative with 'Identity' is also an applicative 
instance (Applicative f) => Applicative (Lift f) where
    pure = Pure
    Pure f <*> Pure x = Pure (f x)
    Pure f <*> Other y = Other (f <$> y)
    Other f <*> Pure x = Other (($ x) <$> f)
    Other f <*> Other y = Other (f <*> y)
```

Now, if we add in the `Constant` functor/applicative:

```
newtype Constant a b = Constant { getConstant :: a }

instance Functor (Constant a) where
    fmap f (Constant x) = Constant x

instance (Monoid a) => Applicative (Constant a) where
    pure _ = Constant mempty
    Constant x <*> Constant y = Constant (x `mappend` y)
```

...we can assemble the "applicative `Either`" from the other responses out of `Lift` and `Constant`:

```
type Error e a = Lift (Constant e) a
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Will Ness explains in his answer, the key difference is that with Monads there's a choice between different executions paths at every step. Let's make this potential choice syntactically visible by implementing a function for sequencing four times. First for applicative `f`, and then for monad `m`:

```
seq4A :: Applicative f => f a -> f [a]
seq4A f =
    f <**> (
    f <**> (
    f <**> (
    f <&> (\a1 a2 a3 a4 -> 
        [a1, a2, a3, a4]))))

seq4M :: Monad m => m a -> m [a]
seq4M m =
    m >>= (\a1 ->
    m >>= (\a2 ->
    m >>= (\a3 ->
    m >>= (\a4 -> 
        return [a1, a2, a3, a4]))))
```

The `seq4M` function has the values resulting from the monadic action available at every step and could thus make a choice at every step. On the other hand the `seq4A` function only has the values available at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my view on this "iffy miffy" thing, as I understand this everything inside the context get applied, so for example:

```
iffy :: Applicative f => f Bool -> f a -> f a -> f a
iffy fb ft fe = cond <$> fb <*> ft <*> fe   where
            cond b t e = if b then t else e

case 1>> iffy (Just True) (Just “True”) Nothing ->> Nothing
```

upps should be Just "True" ... but

```
 case 2>> iffy (Just False) (Just “True”) (Just "False") ->> Just "False"
```

(the "good" choice is made inside the context)
I explained this to myself this way, just before the end of the computation in case >>1 we get something like that in the "chain" :

```
Just (Cond True "True") <*> something [something being "accidentaly" Nothing]
```

which according by definition of Applicative is evaluated as:

```
fmap (Cond True "True") something
```

which when "something" **is** Nothing becomes a Nothing according to Functor constraint (fmap over Nothing gives Nothing). And it is not possible to define a Functor with "fmap f Nothing = something" end of story.