# Best way to create Maybe type as the result of Maybe parts

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I have a `Request` type:

```
data Request =
  Request {
     reqType :: RequestType,
     path    :: String,
     options :: [(String, String)]
  } deriving Show
```

And I'm parsing it (from a raw `HTTP` request), as follows:

```
parseRawRequest :: String -> Request
parseRawRequest rawReq =
    Request {
        reqType = parseRawRequestType rawReq,
        path    = parseRawRequestPath rawReq,
        options = parseRawRequestOps  rawReq
  }
```

Now, the calls to `parseRawRequestType`, `parseRawRequestPath` (etc) can fail. To make my code more resilient, I've changed their type signature from:

```
parseRawRequestType :: String -> RequestType
```

to

```
parseRawRequestType :: String -> Maybe RequestType
```

But what is the best way to turn `parseRawRequest` into a `Maybe Request` ? Do I have to manually check each component (`reqType`, `path`, `options`) for `Nothing`, or is there a different way that I'm missing?

There must be a way to somehow compose the object creation and `Nothing`-checking!

I wrote the following, but it feels messy and not ideal: (Untested)

```
parseRawRequest :: String -> Maybe Request
parseRawRequest rawReq
  | Nothing `elem` [reqType, path, options] = Nothing
  | otherwise                               =
    Just Request { reqType=reqType, path=path, options=options }
  where reqType = parseRawRequestType rawReq
        path    = parseRawRequestPath rawReq
        options = parseRawRequestOps  rawReq
```

Cheers.

Comment: The words "sum type" in the question title are a little confusing, since your `Request` type is a *product* of several Maybe fields, not a sum of them.

Comment: You're 100% correct. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly the pattern that Applicative Functors (`Control.Applicative`) represent.  Applicatives are like regular Functors, but with two extra operations:

```
pure :: a -> f a
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

`pure` lets you put any value into an applicative, and means that for any applicative, you can write an `fmap` as `fmap f x = pure f <*> x`.

The interesting operator in this case is `<*>`. The idea is that if you have a function "inside" the functor, you can apply it to another value in the functor.  If you do `Request <$> (_ :: Maybe RequestType)`, you will get something of type `Maybe (String -> [(String, String)] -> Request)`.  The `<*>` operator will then let you take this and apply it to something of type `Maybe String` to get `Maybe [(String, String)] -> Request)` and so on.

Example:

```
data RequestType
data Request =
  Request { reqType :: RequestType, path :: String, options :: [(String, String)] }

parseRawRequestType :: String -> Maybe RequestType
parseRawRequestType = undefined
parseRawRequestPath :: String -> Maybe String
parseRawRequestPath = undefined
parseRawRequestOps :: String -> Maybe [(String, String)]
parseRawRequestOps = undefined
parseRawRequest :: String -> Maybe Request
parseRawRequest rawReq = Request <$> parseRawRequestType rawReq
                                 <*> parseRawRequestPath rawReq
                                 <*> parseRawRequestOps rawReq
```

Notice however that the function being applied must have type `f (a -> b)` instead of the `a -> m b` of the common monadic bind operator.  In the effectful context, you can think of this as `<*>` giving a way to sequence effects without inspecting intermediate results, whereas `>>=` gives you a little more power (note: the essential difference between the power of an Applicative Functor and a Monad is a function `join :: m (m a) -> m a`. Can you think how to obtain `>>=` with `<*>` and `join`?). However, Applicatives are a more general interface, which means that you can use them in more cases, and they can sometimes have nice properties when it comes to analysis/optimization.  There seems to be a decent overview of Applicatives vs Monads and when you might want to use Applicatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342184/difference-between-monad-and-applicative-in-haskell).