# 'join' for Applicatives?

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for the following function:

`Applicative f => f (f a) -> f a`

[Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=applicative+f+%3D%3E+f+%28f+a%29+-%3E+f+a) shows me `join`:

```
>:t join
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

Is there a function that matches my desired signature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What advantage does Monad give us over an Applicative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409260/what-advantage-does-monad-give-us-over-an-applicative)

Answer (score 51):

To expand a bit on [Carl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113360#answer-29113555), If there was such a thing as `join`, but for applicatives:

```
class Applicative f => ApplicativeWithJoin f where
    join' :: f (f a) -> f a
```

Then you would automatically have a monad:

```
instance ApplicativeWithJoin m => Monad m where
    return = pure
    x >>= f = join' (f <$> x)
```

Answer (score 46):

There is no such function. `join` is explicitly what `Applicative` lacks and `Monad` has.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on SingleNegationElimination's  answer:

- `Applicative`'s `<*>` allows you to combine effects together and their values inside together, or manipulate a value inside using `<$>`, but you can't make an effect depend on a value of a previous computation.
- `Monad`s, on the other hand, allow an effect to be determined by the result of the previous computation, as witnessed by `>>=`.

With any `Applicative` you can first use `<$>` to convert a value of type `a` inside `f a` into some `f b`, so you'll get `f (f b)`. But without `join`, the inner `f b` is just another value, there is no way how you can combine it with the outer one that is actually executed. Adding `join` makes it possible, allowing to define the full power of `Monad`.