# Lifted „if“-function behaves unexpectedly

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, io-monad, lifting

in my program I use a function `if'` defined in one of the modules instead of the built-in `if-then-else` construct. It is defined trivially and works just fine.

However, there's one place in code where I need to apply it to monad values (`IO` in my case), i.e. the type signature should look somewhat like `IO Bool -> IO a -> IO a -> IO a`.
Naturally, I tried to lift it.

```
if' <$> mb <*> action1 <*> action2
```

But when I try to evaluate the expression, I don't get what I expect.

```
*Main> if' <$> return True <*> putStrLn "yes" <*> putStrLn "no"
yes
no
```

I know that `<*>` description reads „sequential application“, so maybe it's that. But what is happening here? Can I fix it without writing a whole new dedicated function?

Comment: In the last expression, the `if` statement only controls the value that is returned - both branches must be executed in order to even compute those values, because it uses the applicative interface to IO. You probably want `return True >>= \b -> if' b (putStrLn "yes") (putStrLn "no")` - note how `if'` is applied *directly* to the different branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(<*>)` evaluates both of its arguments, so it effectively a pipeline of applications lifted over some applicative. The ability to inspect values and change the future of the computation is the extra power that the `Monad` class has over `Applicative` so you need to use that instead e.g.

```
mif' :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a
mif' bm xm ym = bm >>= (\b -> if b then xm else ym)
```

Comment: @Carl has a great answer pertaining to this at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409260/what-advantage-does-monad-give-us-over-an-applicative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409260/what-advantage-does-monad-give-us-over-an-applicative)